# Почему посылают в баню?

Tags: фразеология

Интересно, а почему, желая "послать" человека, его посылают именно в баню? Что такого плохого в бане? С мытьем это, вроде как, не связано.

Comment: А правда...)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что это намек на немытость собеседника, типа "от тебя пахнет". 
Ну или на вшивость.
Надо бы точно посмотреть, когда возникает желание туда послать...  Когда собеседник сказал глупость (по мнению посылающего).

Comment: Мне кажется, что посыл в баню имеет более шутливую окраску, нежели посыл... скажем там, в другое место))) Вроде и послал, и не обидел)))

Comment: Ну да, согласен. 
Мой ответ, вроде, никак тому не противоречит.

Answer (score 11):

НЕ знаю, возможно что и не права... Но у нас "иди в баню" говорят не тогда. когда собеседник сказал глупость, а тогда, когда пристал. Т.е. значение фразеологизма "иди в баню" - отстань. И вспоминается другое выражение: пристал как банный лист. Вроде как антонимичные по смыслу получаются: пристал как банный лист - отстань, иди в баню

Comment: >Но у нас "иди в баню" говорят не тогда. когда собеседник сказал глупость, а тогда, когда пристал.  
  
Да. И это тоже. Но одно другого не исключает.  
Под "глупостью" я имел в виду прежде всего "глупый совет".

Answer (score 8):

Есть еще такое предположение: баня считалась прибежищем **нечисти** (например, банника или шишиги). Там никогда не было икон, охранявших человека. В бане устраивали святочные  гадания. Если учесть все эти обстоятельства, то *послать в баню* значило примерно то же, что *послать к лешему или черту*, своего рода форма проклятия.

Comment: Это точно. Бани никогда не святили по причине срамной наготы посещающих. 
Насчет нечисти - не знаю, все-таки это суеверия, а вот чертей там точно можно было встретить.

Comment: Интересно...

Comment: Эту версию излагают также здесь: http://chtooznachaet.ru/vyrazhenie_idi_v_banju.html

Comment: «... Послать в баню значило примерно то же, что послать к лешему...». Не сильно значило, коли к 70-м население запамятовало.

Answer (score 3):

Поискал в Национальном корпусе русского языка: впервые фразеологизм зафиксирован в таком значении в 1969 году. Источник: "Ирония судьбы, или С лёгким паром!". (Фильм вышел позднее. В 1969 году появился спектакль с аналогичным сюжетом.)

Напомню контекст. К Жене Лукашину пришёл его школьный товарищ Павел Судаков. Но наткнулся на пороге на Марину Дмитриевну, его маму, которая не хотела пускать Павла внутрь. И вот между ними происходит диалог (первая фраза — Евгения):

> – Мама, кто там опять? – послышался
> голос Лукашина.
>
> – Телеграмма от тети Веры! – и глазом
> не моргнув, сочинила родная мать.
>
> – А вы, Марина Дмитриевна, с детства
> учили нас говорить только правду! –
> укоризненно сказал Павел.
>
> – Бывают обстоятельства, когда неплохо
> соврать! – доверительно объяснила
> Марина Дмитриевна.
>
> **– Но Саша и Миша ждут нас в бане! А прямо из бани я еду на аэродром!**
>
> – Сегодня повеселитесь без Жени!
> Кстати, зачем ты едешь в Ленинград?
>
> – Ира застряла там в командировке.
> Требует, чтобы я прилетел встречать с
> ней Новый год. – Павел еще больше
> понизил голос. – Я никому не скажу!
> Все-таки... что происходит?
>
> – Пока это тайна... Узнаешь... в свое
> время. – Видно было, что дразнить
> Павла доставляло Марине Дмитриевне
> удовольствие.
>
> – У Жени от меня нет тайн!
>
> – **Иди в баню!** – Марина Дмитриевна
> защелкнула дверь и вернулась в кухню,
> на пункт подслушивания.

Так что первоначально в неё не вкладывался какой-то особый смысл. Но фраза звучит очень ярко, узнаваемо, и смысл её (выводимый из контекста) весьма однозначен. Думаю, что именно по этим причинам эти слова пошли "в народ".

Хотя не исключаю, что у "иди в баню" были какие-то предвестники. Но найти про них ничего не смог. Поэтому версия с "народным" происхождением кажется мне неверной.

Comment: В нац. Корпусе далеко не все есть.

Comment: Разумеется. Но в других источниках я тоже не нашёл ничего конкретного. Предположений — масса. Но их наличие ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: Иди  ты  в  баню, заодно  и  помоешься !  А  с  таким  выражением  вы   не  знакомы ?  И  в  начале  60-х  уже  было.  Правда,  в  текстах  не  встречал.

Comment: >впервые фразеологизм зафиксирован в таком значении в 1969 году.

А б р а м (читает). "Товарищ Абрам! Я долго думала и пришла к заключению, что дальше так продолжаться не может. При создавшихся объективных условиях..." Ну вот, я говорил, что она докопается до объективных условий...  
  
Е м е л ь я н. И я говорил то же. Помнишь, когда в баню шли...   

Катаев, "Квадратура круга" 1924.

Это то, что вспомнилось.

Comment: bernard, не могу комментировать: к сожалению, в те времена я ещё не был способен воспринимать какие бы то ни было фразеологизмы.

behemotus, при всём глубочайшем уважении, эти слова здесь употреблены скорее в прямом смысле, поэтому к обсуждению какого-либо отношения они почти не имеют.

Comment: >эти слова здесь употреблены скорее в прямом смысле

Не думаю. Контекст не предполагает. Да и найти можно много чего. 

Во всяком случае когда я смотрел первый раз "Иронию судьбы" все восприняли ту баню именно как аллюзию на хорошо известное выражение. Я, слава богу, был во вполне взрослом возрасте.

>Иди ты в баню, заодно и помоешься!  

Вообще-то там скорее "пойд**ём** в баню"

Answer (score 0):

Если допустить, что "баня"... это то, что осталось от слова "баняк" ... казан/чугунок/горшок ... етимологию, которого предлагают от польского слова "корыто" ...

"иди в баню..." -  это тоже, что и .. 
"go to pot"    -  "иди в горшок/чугунок" - пожелание конца/смерти в английском...

И, возможно, в других исторических германских диалектах, поскольку слово "баняк" до сих пор в ходу во Львове, который, как известно до недавнего времени был частью Австро-Венгрии.

По смыслу, да и по звучанию, "go to pot" похоже на "kaputgehen" в немецком языке, хотя генезис последнего прослеживают из фр. "Capot" ... см."всезнающий"гугл...

Comment: Глубоко копать не надо. Такого «посыла» (среди многих иных бранных) не было до известной сцены из фильма. Если Вам пришлось слышать его ранее, то сообщите подробнее об этом событии.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас говорят "отправить в бан", "забанить".
Я знаю что на фене и у хипарей много слов из английского, немецкого, брали и переделывали. Типа "чикса" (chica), "клёво" (clever)...